# Problema con react-native-image-picker en ios

Tags: ios, react-native, reactjs

estoy usando esta librería ( react-native-image-picker ) en una app que estoy desarrollando en el trabajo y no termino de conseguir que me funcione en ios.

Cuando pincho en el botón del componente me sale la opción para elegir entre la galería del iphone y usar la cámara para conseguir la imagen, se bloquea y se sale de la app del emulador.

He seguido el tutorial, he probado varias soluciones, he estado revisando los permisos, no se me ocurre que mas puedo hacer.

Os pongo el info.plist

```html
<dict>
 <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
 <string>Would like access to your photo gallery</string>
 <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
 <string>Would like to use your camera</string>
 <key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
 <string>Would like to your microphone (for videos)</string>
```

un saludo, gracias a todos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo he solucionado, actualizando la librería a la ultima versión.

Comment: Por favor recuerda [aceptar tu propia respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Saludos.